# Terraform dynamic list element

Tags: google-cloud-platform, module, terraform

I have a Terraform (version is up to date) module to create GCP projects. Depending on some variables (dev = true/false // test = true/false // prod = true/false) a different amount of GCP projects is created at the same time by the module. The name of the projects is based on variables plus a stage prefix.

```
resource "google_project" "project-dev" {
  count               = var.create_dev ? 1 : 0
  name                = "${var.project}-dev"
  ...
}

resource "google_project" "project-test" {
  count               = var.create_test ? 1 : 0
  name                = "${var.project}-test"
  ...
}

resource "google_project" "project-prod" {
  count               = var.create_prod ? 1 : 0
  name                = "${var.project}-prod"
  ...
}
```

I want to use the resource `google_billing_budget` to create an overall budget alarm for all created projects in this module. The number of projects (`budget_filter` -> `projects` in the resource `google_billing_budget`) can differ as mentioned above.

How can I add elements dynamically in the `projects` list of `google_billing_budget`?

The current solution is the following:

```
resource "google_billing_budget" "budget_alarm" {
  ...

  budget_filter {
    projects = compact([var.create_dev ? "projects/${var.project}-dev}" : "",
                        var.create_test ? "projects/${var.project}-test}" : "",
                        var.create_prod ? "projects/${var.project}-prod" : ""])
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried what you showed as the current solution? What improvements would you like to make to it?

Comment: In your google project's `project-prod` resource, the variable on count should be `create_prod` ?

Comment: @Abel Yes, copy and paste error. I fixed it.

Comment: @MartinAtkins Is there a better solution provided by TF for this kind of situation?

Comment: It's hard to say what might be "better" because it's not clear yet what you disliked or what didn't work with what you tried already.  If you can ask a more specific question I'm happy to try to answer it.